# MySql Sort by Date in JOIN Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

I am trying to display a news feed of items from two tables.

```
Table 1: News - Id / Title / Date
Table 2: Shared_News - Id / News_Id / Date
```

`News_Id` from `Shared_News` is actually the Id from the `News` table. Now the scenario...

My News Feed has to display the items from the News table and also the Shared_News items. The Shared_News items are to be merged with the News items according to the date they were shared.

Lets take an example where we show Id's 2,4,6,8 from the `News` table sorted by date as below

```
8
6
4
2
```

Now lets support someone shared the `News` item 5 with the user on a date after the article 8 was published, it was entered in the `Shared_News` table. I wish to show the below order

```
5
8
6
4
2
```

Now if item 1 was shared after item 4 was published the order should be as below

```
5
8
6
1
4
2
```

Could someone help me as the Left Join I am doing is not working. Below is my code / I am using Codeigniter Framework.

$stories_finalized below is the merged list of news id's and shared news id's.

```
$select =   array(
    'users.name',
    'story.id as story_id',
    'story.date',
    'story.title',
    'story.user_id',
    'share.date as shared_story_date'
);
$where  =   array('story.show' => 1);
$this->db
        ->select($select)
        ->where_in('story.id', $stories_finalized)
        ->join('users', 'users.id = story.user_id')
        ->join('share', 'share.story_id = story.id', 'LEFT')
        ->where($where)
        ->order_by('share.date, story.date', 'DESC')
        ->limit(STORY_QUERY_LIMIT, $from);
```

Data stored is as below in the Story Table

```
59 | This is an example story | 2013-09-20
45 | This is the title of the shared story | 2013-08-12
```

Data stored in the Share table is as below

```
1 | 45 | 2013-12-24
```

In the end, I want the data to be like below

```
45 | This is the title of the shared story | 2013-08-12
59 | This is an example story | 2013-09-20
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: could we have some actual data not just the ids? Two table?

Comment: @PeterRing yes we definitely can fetch data.

Comment: I removed SQL Server tags because this is about MySQL, and added the codeigniter, because it is about Code Igniter.

Comment: @foxybagga, what PeterRing meant was, can you show *us* the data. We don't know how it's being stored.

Comment: is there any  possibility of empty date stored in `shared_story_date`?

Comment: @kumar_v well, the stories which are directly from the story table have shared_story_date as null

Comment: for starters, try ORDER BY instead of order_by (no underscore)

Comment: does codeigniter use different mysql syntax?

Comment: then how are you identify the story is published or not?

Comment: The way it's ordered now "share.date, story.date', 'DESC'" you will have share.date *ascending* and story.date *descending*. Is this what you want?

Comment: @ethrbunny well I want a list of stories in desc dates but if there are shared stories - I want to fit them in that list respective to their shared date...

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the last share date per news (if any). So find these, join them with news, and then order by share date if available, else with publishing date:

```
select news.title, news.date_published, last_shared.share_date
from news
left outer join
(
  select news_id, max(date_shared) as share_date
  from shared_news
  group by news_id
) last_shared on (last_shared.news_id = news.id)
order by coalesce(last_shared.share_date, news.date_published) desc;
```

By the way: Don't call your columns "date", for this is an SQL word.

Comment: `date is keyword` absolutely right. this may be reason for the problem

Comment: @thorsten - I cannot figure out how to do this - its tough and the users join is killing it.

Comment: @thorsten-kettner - I cannot figure it out. Could you please help me with a few tips please... I have pasted below what I am using...

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late. Please see my comments to what you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing. I use Codeigniter.

```
$this->db->select('users.name, story.date, story.title, IFNULL(share.date, story.date) as sort_date', FALSE)
->where_in('story.id', $stories_finalized)
->where(array(
     'story.show' => 1
))
->join('users', 'users.id = story.user_id', 'INNER')
->join('share', 'share.story_id = story.id', 'LEFT OUTER')
->group_by('story.id')
->order_by('sort_date', 'DESC');
```

Thanks to Thorsten for pointing out the duplicate story_id's and to Dr. Fu Manchu for pointing out the way to get near to it.

Comment: Either make users.name a part of the GROUP BY clause or access it with an aggregate function such as MIN or MAX.

Comment: I don't know how Codeigniter handles subselects in the FROM clause. Can you simply write "->join('(select ... from ...)',..." instead of "->join('share',..."? Otherwise I would recommand to make the subquery a view called "latest_share" and access that view "->join('latest_share', ..." instead of the table.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks a lot for the comment. I solved the issue by adding ->join('share', 'share.story_id = story.id AND share.user_id = '.$user_id, 'LEFT OUTER'). The major issue is searching in this - I can successfully search by story.title but I cannot search by user.name which is something I wanted to do. Search by either or both.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You select stories and join the authors (users), i.e. one user for each story - so far my understanding. Then you join all shares of the story which leads to many records per story rather than one (which is why I told you to find the latest share per story and use this). Now you tell me that you reduce shares by limiting share users to .$user_id (who is this?) Is there a guarantee that one user can only have one share per story?

Comment: Now you want to search. Are you talking about a where clause? You join story and user, so you can use all fields of the two tables in your where clause. That shouldn't be a problem. So I wonder what's hindering you. My suggestion: Think clearly what you want to select: Which share for the story? The shares of a particular user or the stories of a user? When you have thought it all through, then use SQL to see if you get what you want. Once this works, write the corresponding Codeigniter code. Good luck!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I want to select stories from the main story table, join it with the shared stories to get a final list of stories, join it with users table to get owners of those stories. Then I want to search this group by story title or username.

Comment: No, you are not being precise. You select _which_ shares with a story? If you join _all_ shares with their Story then you select shares rather than stories. I assumed you want to select the _latest_ share with each story. Hence the according subselect in the from clause.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner apologies for being unclear... let me explain again. There is a story table, share table and a users table and I want to show stories to a particular user ($user_id) which could be from any user on the network. Now I first select stories from the story table for the user, then I select the stories from the share table for the user. I combine and array_unique those to get the total stories for the user. Then I get the details of all those stories $stories_finalized using the above query and sort those with either share_date or story_date which ever is earlier.

Comment: I also want to search this list by username or by story_title

Comment: Don't apologize to me. What I am trying to tell you: It is not I you should make things clear to, but you :-) To me it seems now you want to do two very different things: 1) Find all stories a user ($user_id) wrote or shared. 2) Find all users who wrote or shared a specific story ($story_title). Don't try to do completely different things in the same select statement, but write two different ones. As to finding all stories a user wrote or shared: You would have to access the story table two times: one time for the stories the user has written, one time for the stories the user has shared.

Comment: Another thing: You should really try with pure SQL before transforming it into Codeigniter. Otherwise you'll never know if a faulty result stems from faulty logic or from not having it coded correctly in Codeigniter. (This is of course just my opinion. You may think otherwise.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I shall try first it in pure SQL. May be that's what is supposed to be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT users.*, story.*, IFNULL(share.`date`, story.`date`) AS sort_date FROM 
users INNER JOIN story ON users.id = story.user_id
LEFT JOIN share ON share.story_id = story.id
WHERE story.id IN (....)
ORDER BY sort_date DESC
```

I cannot help with translating it into codeigniter syntax though...

Comment: Shall do and get back

Comment: Strange, it shouldn't. This doesn't give you the stories ordered by last share date, but all shares (i.e. one story multiple times). This is not what you asked. But well, maybe it is what you meant :-)

Comment: It doesn't - its buggy.